# Symfony 3 Inject translator to Form Type

Tags: php, forms, service, translation, symfony

I'm currently working on a FormType where I want to use a translator for special attributes.

```
$builder->add("firstname", TextType::class, array(
              "label" => "person.label.firstname",
              "attr" => array(
                  "placeholder" => "person.label.firstname",
                  "pattern" => "^[a-zA-Z \-]+",
                  "oninvalid" =>  'setCustomValidity("' . $translator->trans('person.validity.firstname') . '")')
            ))
```

So how do I get the `$translator` to work? Do I have to inject it as a service (how?) or should I pass it as a parameter to this formtype (still how?) ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is all pretty well explained [here: *How to Access Services or Config from Inside a Form*](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_dependencies.html).

Comment: that fields (label and placeholder) should be translated out of the box by symfony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Matteo, it should work straight out of the box in your form.

[project]\app\config\config.yml should have:

```
framework:
    ....
    translator: {fallbacks:["en"]}
    translator: 
        paths: 
           - "@[App]Bundle/Resources/translations"
    ...
```

And under "[projet]\src[App]Bundle\Ressources\translations\" all the files: "messages.[lang 2 char code].yml"

in your case the file "messages.en.yml" should look like:

```
person:
   label:
      firstname: "firstname"
      lastname: "lastname"
```

Also becareful the ".yml" files don't accept "tab sign" (only "space sign").

Validation message should also be under "[projet]\src[App]Bundle\Ressources\translations\" in files named as this: "validators.[lang 2 char code].yml"

In your case "validators.en.yml":

```
person:
   validity:
      firstname: "firstname doesn't match"
```

The validity rule for "firstname" should be an annotation in the data_class used with your form.

```
class [YOUR DATA_CLASS] {
    /**
    * @Assert\NotBlank()
    * @Assert\Regex(
    *   groups= {[if needed]}
    *   pattern = "^[a-zA-Z \-]+",
    *   match= "false",
    *   message = "person.validity.firstname")
    *   
    */
    public $firstname;
}
```